# Runtime type of interface

Tags: .net, entity-framework, types, interface

I use entity framework with `DbContext` T4 code generator. The code generated includes entity objects with child entity collections. They are declared as `ICollection<T>`. Now, I found out at runtime they actually become `HashSet<T>`. How .NET handles such cases? Can someone point me to the documentation where I can find information on default implementation types of specific interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no “default implementation” for an interface. If a method returns an interface, that method decides which type is actually returned. In your case, that's most likely something inside Entity Framework.